# How can I eliminate Rmarkdown error in parse when I knit?

Tags: r

I am getting an "error in parse`````````; attempt to use zero-length variable" when I try to knit the below.

It always occurs at line 38. Ideas?

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/varsel/")
library(olsrr)
simplemodel <- read.csv("~/Dropbox/varsel/Ranalyses var sel/simplemodel.csv")
model<-lm(out ~., data =simplemodel)
aicresult<- ols_step_backward_aic(model, details = TRUE)
aicresult
```

````
38 setwd("~/Dropbox/varsel/")
library(BMS)
library(dply)
swmodel<-read.csv ("~/Dropbox/causation project/sachs warner/mainvarsnomiss")
swmodelminuscol1<-select(swmodel,-1)
swbma<- bms(swmodelminuscol1, burn=100000, iter=200000, g="BRIC", mprior="uniform", nmodel=2000, mcmc="bd", user.int=FALSE)
coef(swbma, exact = TRUE)```
````

Comment: Maybe try to remove that line and set the working directory with Control+ Shift + H?

Comment: Thanks. I have removed that line but it doesn't help. I have to admit I don't quite understand how wd is set in Rmd--the code works file in R.

Comment: Uhm, then maybe just read those tables using the full path. So that'll make it independent from where the wd is? Example: T/home/harold/documents/dropbox/.../